# Taking a section of a PHP PDO string and insert it into img element

Tags: php, pdo

just a quick question.

So I am fetching a string from my SQL table using PDO and printing it to my front end, I am currently using this code:

```
'.implode('</div><div>', explode(',', $row["String"])) .'
```

As you can see this code is exploding the string with each comma and putting each into a div.

I am now wanting to change the output but having a bit of trouble taking the first part of the string and putting it into an img.

Here is an example of the column in my SQL table:

```
http://www.imgurl.com/image.jpg,http://www.imgurl.com/image2.jpg,http://www.imgurl.com/image3.jpg, http://www.imgurl.com/image4.jpg
```

As you can see they are separated by a comma, I want to insert that first jpg url into the src section of a img element.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to 1 liner it, then you could do:

```
.'<img src="'.implode('"/><img src="',explode(',', $row["String"])).'"/>'.
```

Which will produce something like:

```
<img src="http://www.imgurl.com/image.jpg"/><img src="http://www.imgurl.com/image2.jpg"/><img src="http://www.imgurl.com/image3.jpg"/><img src="http://www.imgurl.com/image4.jpg"/>
```

To just get the first array element of a string in php 5.4+:

```
echo '<img src="'.explode(',', $row['String'])[0].'"/>';
```

Otherwise:

```
$parts = explode(',', $row['String']);
echo '<img src="'.$parts[0].'"/>';
```

Comment: Thanks for this, although I only want to use one img element and only the first url in the table string, so it would produce <img src="http://www.imgurl.com/image.jpg"/> instead of the others also.

Comment: @DaleDoback Sure. I've provided that above. The one liner is only applicable to php 5.4+.

Answer (score 0):

```
$images = explode(',', $row['String']);
echo '<img src="'.$images[0].'"/>';
```